# ionic use Service to share data between controllers

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-services

I'm trying to share data between controllers but once the data is set in my service it won't change again.

**The Idea**

I have a page of items I'm calling *coupons* and clicking on an item in *coupons* takes you to a *single-coupon*. When I click an item in *coupons* I want to save the item data in a service so that I can have access to it in *single-coupon*

**The Service**

```
.service('userService', function() {
  var userService = this;

  userService.sharedObject = null;
})
```

**Some Code inside CouponsCtrl**

```
.controller('CouponsCtrl', function($scope, $state, userService) {
  $scope.couponClick = function(coupon) {
    userService.sharedObject = coupon;
    $state.go('single-coupon');
  }
})
```

**The Issue**

This works the first time like you would expect but then if I go back to **coupons** and click a new coupon item then the **single-coupon** page still shows the old data! What do I need to do differently?

Comment: I don't see where you are injecting your `userService` service into your controller.

Comment: I just added that part. It looks like: .controller('CouponsCtrl', function($scope, $state, userService)

Comment: I'm not positive this is a problem, but I'm used to seeing services return an object.  Like an object whose properties are the shared objects `return userService;`?

Comment: declare `userService.sharedObject = {};` instead of `null`

Comment: how did you bind `sharedObject` with your view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your service should have getter and setter which would set & get data

**Service**

```
.service('userService', function() {
  var userService = this;
  userService.sharedObject = {};

  userService.getCoupon = function(){
     return userService.sharedObject.Coupon;
  }

  userService.setCoupon = function(value){
     userService.sharedObject.Coupon = value;
  }
});
```

Then you could easily set a value of data by using set `setCoupon` & getData by `getCoupon` method

**CouponsCtrl**

```
.controller('CouponsCtrl', function($scope, $state, userService) {
  $scope.couponClick = function(coupon) {
    userService.setCoupon(coupon);
    $state.go('single-coupon');
  }
});
```

**SingleCouponCtrl**(singleCouponCtrl will get value by)

```
.controller('singleCouponCtrl', function($scope, $state, userService) {
   //other code here
   if($state.params.id == 0) //id is of coupon id
     $scope.coupon = userService.setCoupon({}); //for your issue
   $scope.coupon = userService.getCoupon();
});
```

Comment: Where is .service('userService', function() {  included?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to move data between one state and another, ui-router already provides for this behavior:

```
$stateProvider.state('coupon', { url: '/coupon/:paramOne/:paramTwo', .... }); 
$state.go('app.page', { paramOne: 'testOne', paramTwo: 'testTwo });
```

Then, you che retrive this parameters injecting $stateParams into your Controller,

Comment: The object is a json version of a wordpress object so it comes with 20+ properties accompanied by numerous levels of nesting. That seems like a bit much to be passing via a querystring no?