# How to Pass id and name from the first form, and Show only the name in second form in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I Have two forms.In these forms am getting input from the first form and show that in the second form, Which means if the user selected the currency from the dropdown, i need to pass id and the the currency name. But show only the currency name in the second form. I tried one method (dont know whether it is correct or not) it is showing the id only. am new to angular. is there anyway to solve this?

HTML

```
         <div class="row text-center" ng-show="firstform">
                <form name="validation">
            <label>Currency</label>
             <select ng-model="CurrencyId" ng-selected="CurrencyId" class="form-control" id="CurrencyId">
              <option ng:repeat="CurrencyId in currencyList" ng-selected="selectedCurrencyType == CurrencyId.id" value={{CurrencyId.currencyId}}>{{CurrencyId.name}}</option>
            </select>

             <label>Grade</label>
             <select ng-model="GradeId" ng-selected="GradeId" class="form-control" id="GradeId">
            <option ng:repeat="GradeId in RaceGradeList" ng-selected="selectedGrade == GradeId.id" value={{GradeId.id}}>{{GradeId.gradeName}}</option>
            </select>
    <button type="submit"value="add" ng-click="savedetails()" />
       </form>
    </div>


      <div class="row text-center" ng-show="secondform">
     <form name="thirdform">
     <ul >
      <li><p>Currency:{{CurrencyId}}</p> </li>
     <li><p>Grade:{{GradeId}}</p> </li>
     </ul>
     </form>
</div>
```

angular controller

```
    $scope.savedetails = function () {
            $scope.firstform= false;
            $scope.secondform = true;

        }
```

Comment: Can you show a plunker ?

Comment: You could use service to persist data while transitioning from one view to another...

Comment: @PankajParkar actually am new to angular. I dont know how to do it.. can you provide a working code

Comment: @Coder please refer [Service to share data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29798853/2435473) It will definitely help you.

Comment: are both your form in the same view or different views?

Comment: @Manish different views in a same page.. thats why i used this code `$scope.firstform= false; $scope.secondform = true;`

Comment: Can you show us the working example of code in plunker or fiddle ?

Comment: @PankajParkar i just need to pass value between two views.. here i didnt having 2 controllers nah?

Comment: You want the Currency name to displayed or the currency id in the second form? because in ng-model you have used `CurrencyId` and the value for options is `value={{CurrencyId.currencyId}}` ?

Comment: @manish i need to display the currency name to display in the second form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most simplest solution that you can go for. Instead of having the `value={{CurrencyId.currencyId}}` set it as `value={{CurrencyId.name}}` for the options in the dropdown and you are good to go. Below is the demo for the same. But if you want to save `currencyId` as the value then you will have to iterate over the array and find the name based on the selected `currencyId` and then show that in the view.

**UPDATE**

Updated the code to have the `currencyId` being stored as the selected value and then based on that showing the name in the view.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currencyList = [{
      currencyId: 1,
      name: "INR"
    },
    {
      currencyId: 2,
      name: "$"
    },
    {
      currencyId: 3,
      name: "#"
    }
  ];
  $scope.currencyChanged = function() {
 var selectedCurrency;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.currencyList.length; i++) {
      var thisCurr = $scope.currencyList[i];
      if ($scope.CurrencyId == thisCurr.currencyId)
        selectedCurrency = thisCurr.name;
    }
    return selectedCurrency;
  }
  $scope.firstform = true;
  $scope.savedetails = function() {
    $scope.firstform = false;
    $scope.secondform = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row text-center" ng-show="firstform">
    <form name="validation">
      <label>Currency</label>
      <select ng-model="CurrencyId" ng-selected="CurrencyId" class="form-control" id="CurrencyId">
              <option ng:repeat="CurrencyId in currencyList" ng-selected="CurrencyId == CurrencyId.currencyId" value={{CurrencyId.currencyId}}>{{CurrencyId.name}}</option>
            </select>
      <button type="button" value="add" ng-click="savedetails()">Save Details</button>
    </form>
  </div>


  <div class="row text-center" ng-show="secondform">
    <form name="thirdform">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>Currency:{{currencyChanged()}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: please help me.. How to do this one?? 
 "" if you want to save currencyId as the value then you will have to iterate over the array and find the name based on the selected currencyId and then show that in the view."" am new to angular..

Comment: yes you will have to iterate over the array find the selected currency. wait Will update the answer

Comment: thank you bro.. am struggling with this more than 2 weeks.

Comment: Please let me know if this solves your problem or not?

Comment: ya sure bro.. am trying this one.. ill let you know

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-options , its very flexiable where we can display one value and select either entire object or any specific property.

Please check below plunker , hope it meets your requirement

https://plnkr.co/edit/JQjmAwk62R8rfAlTZ696?p=preview

```
  <select ng-model="CurrencyId" ng-options="currency.id for currency in currencyList" class="form-control" id="CurrencyId" >

        </select>
```

For more details on ng-options , go through below video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqx3zCy4d3I

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<li><p>Currency:{{CurrencyId.name}</p> </li>
```

Comment: please check now